# Select Min Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below. I want to select Min Date and the corresponding ticket status. I tried but is showing me two or more plate numbers. just want the mindate. thanks

```
Date       PlateNo     TickeStatus
01-15-12       A        Open
01-23-12       c        Open
01-17-12       A        Close
02-23-12       c        Open
02-15-12       A        Open
03-23-12       c        Open
03-15-12       A        Close
03-28-12       c        Close
04-15-12       A        Open
04-23-12       c        Close
```

Comment: select min(date) from YourTable?

Comment: can you post what have you tried so far so we can point out which area you got wrong.

Comment: In Oracle, Use SELECT MIN(date), ticketstatus FROM your_table GROUP BY ticketstatus;

Comment: Why is this question put on hold? The second sentence tells exactly what is asked for. The only thing not accounted for is what he wants to happen when the min date has multiple `TickeStatus` (sic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT PlateNo, TicketStatus, [Date]
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlateNo ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS [index],
             PlateNo,
             TicketStatus,
             [Date] 
      FROM YourTable) A
WHERE [index] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. How about the MAX(Date) with corresponding TicketStatus?

Comment: In the OVER clause: ASC -> DESC

Comment: IS this the correct syntax?                                      SELECT CarID, TicketStatus, [EventTime]
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarID ORDER BY [EventTime] ASC->DESC) AS [index],
             CarID,
             TicketStatus,
             [EventTime] 
      FROM vehicle.dbo.Event Event) A
WHERE [index] = 1

Comment: if you want the MAX: SELECT CarID, TicketStatus, [EventTime] FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarID ORDER BY [EventTime] DESC) AS [index], CarID, TicketStatus, [EventTime] FROM vehicle.dbo.Event Event) A WHERE [index] = 1

Comment: Thanks Yossi Dahari. I have a problem on the CarID field because data type is unique identifier. I just want to replace from CarID to PlateNo from Car Table, and on the car table i want to add field Package and Retire. Package = Like '4' ; Retire = 0

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your problem completely. Can you please describe your schema with more details, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Event table constitutes, EventID, EventTime, CarID (FK), TicketStatus. Now i have also table name Car with fields, CarID(unique identifier data type), PlateNo, Package, and retire. Same sql but some additional on the result, like Package with criteria of "4" and retire = 0. Lastly instead of CarID, PlateNo are on the result

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 1 * from TableName order by [Date]
```

that way you will get all the relevant data

Answer (score 1):

But I suggest you to change your *Date* field to other field name, like **the_date** .
It's just for avoid clashed with SQL syntax.

`SELECT *, MIN(the_date) AS min_date FROM YOUR_TABLE;`

Comment: This doesn't get the corresponding ticket status.

Comment: Feel free to check my updated answer.

Comment: That will throw an error on any sensible DBMS

Comment: If this is allowed (it won't work with Oracle, but probably works with MySQL) it still won't return the corresponding status. It will return all rows with an extra column holding min(the_date).

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a group by when you use a Min if I remember well

```
SELECT  MIN(date), PlateNo, Ticket_status
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, PlateNo, Ticket_status
```

Comment: This doesn't get the **corresponding** ticket status.

Comment: Even if we add PlateNo and Ticket in the group by?

Comment: No. This will return all PlateNo and Ticket_status, each accompanied by MIN(date).

Answer (score 0):

ANSI Standard. Simple. Works across all DBs ...

```
select * from YourTable
where [Date] = (select min([Date]) from YourTable)
```

Comment: That's **not** ANSI SQL because of the non-standard "quotes". For an ANSI compatible SQL it should be `"Date"` (double quotes instead of those dreaded square brackets)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The SQL approach is ANSI Standard. The column naming isn't, because that is how the original poster named the column (I'm not going to tell him how to name his columns). So the ONLY thing the poster may need to change is his column name if he moves to another DB. I have no control over that, but he/she does. Something like TicketDate would remove the need for any extra decoration (brackets, quotes, or otherwise).