# populating missing dates and max date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following data from banking system: `date, product code, due date.`

What I need to do is to populate for each product `due_dates` backwards i.e. for previous months but only on condition that `due_date <= date.`

I would also like to populate max_date that is date for the most recent due_date within each product.

As you can see, I may have many due_dates within one product or none.

If there is more than one date, previous shouldn't be overwritten.

This is what it looks like now:

```
    date        product    due_date
------------------------------------------
    2012-01-31    a1           
    2012-02-28    a1           
    2012-01-31    b1           
    2012-02-28    b1           
    2012-03-31    b1           
    2012-04-30    b1       2012-02-18    
    2012-05-31    b1           
    2012-06-30    b1       2012-05-31   
    2012-07-31    b1         
    2012-08-31    b1
    2012-09-30    b1       2012-09-01
    2012-10-31    b1
    2012-04-30    c1         
    2012-05-31    c1         
    2012-06-30    c1       2011-03-01    
    2012-07-31    c1
```

and this is the result I would like to get:

```
     date        product    due_date      max_date
--------------------------------------------------------
     2012-01-31    a1           
     2012-02-28    a1           
     2012-01-31    b1                     2012-09-30
     2012-02-28    b1       2012-02-18    2012-09-30
     2012-03-31    b1       2012-02-18    2012-09-30
     2012-04-30    b1       2012-02-18    2012-09-30
     2012-05-31    b1       2012-05-31    2012-09-30
     2012-06-30    b1       2012-05-31    2012-09-30
     2012-07-31    b1                     2012-09-30
     2012-08-31    b1                     2012-09-30
     2012-09-30    b1       2012-09-01    2012-09-30
     2012-10-31    b1                     2012-09-30
     2012-04-30    c1       2011-03-01    2012-06-30
     2012-05-31    c1       2011-03-01    2012-06-30
     2012-06-30    c1       2011-03-01    2012-06-30
     2012-07-31    c1                     2012-06-30
```

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649286/select-min-date-in-sql/17649509#17649509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/efa14/5/0)

```
SELECT
   t1.date_
 , t1.product
  , case 
    when t1.due_date is not null then t1.due_date
    else ( 
          select max(due_date) 
          from sot t2 
          where t2.product = t1.product 
            and t2.due_date <= t1.date_
            and t2.date_ > t1.date_
          )
    end                                   
                  as due_date
, t3.max_date
FROM 
    sot t1
    left outer join (  select product, max(date_) keep (dense_rank first order by due_date desc)  as max_date 
                       from sot  
                      where due_date is not null 
                      group by product
                    ) t3
    on (t3.product = t1.product)
order by product, date_;
```

The calculation of due_date is not well performant, but i don’t see  any better alternative  in the moment

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I appreciate it. In your query max_date is calculated just like i wanted it to be, but there is a problem with due_dates. I would like them to be populated only in previous months, e.g. due date 2012-05-31 should be only in previous month, not in four months like in the result of your query. The same problem is for due_date 2012-09-01 in product b2 and due_date 2011-03-01 in product c1.

Comment: @FrankMoses a have edit my answer: i have added `and t2.date_ > t1.date_` to the query in ELSE branch

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query maybe will be useful, works fine for your data example,  (you can try this **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2913/16)**):

```
WITH temp1 AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY date_f,product ASC) AS row_num,
             date_f,
             product,
             due_date
   FROM TEST
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT row_num,date_f,product, due_date FROM temp1 WHERE NOT due_date IS NULL
), temp3 AS (
  SELECT product, MAX(date_f) AS max_due_date
  FROM TEST
  WHERE NOT due_date IS NULL
  GROUP BY product
)
SELECT 
to_char(a.date_f,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATE_F, 
a.product,
to_char(NVL(a.due_date,
  (SELECT MIN(b.due_date) 
   FROM temp2 b 
   WHERE b.product = a.product AND b.due_date <= a.date_f AND a.row_num < b.row_num)),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS due_date,
to_char(
  (SELECT c.max_due_date FROM temp3 c
  WHERE c.product = a.product AND ROWNUM = 1),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS max_date
FROM temp1 a
```

NOTE: I could not do better at the moment :(